# VBA for Outlook not parsing email correctly

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am writing a VBA for outlook that will go through emails in my specific folder and go through the email's body and parse a specific line and then save it to an excel file. So far I am not getting any errors and when I run it, it saves an Excel file, but its only prints out an "email" string that I echo within the program, it's not parsed.

So I am having a bit of a problem parsing the proper information from the emails in the outlook folder. In matter of fact, I'm not sure if it's even parsing anything at all.

```
For iCtr = 1 To OutlookNameSpace.Folders.Item(1).Folders.Count
    ' handle case sensitivity as I can't type worth a crap
     If LCase(OutlookNameSpace.Folders.Item(1).Folders(iCtr).Name) = LCase(strTargetFolder) Then
     'found our target :)
        Set outlookFolder = OutlookNameSpace.Folders.Item(1).Folders(iCtr)
     Exit For  ' found it so lets move on
    End If
 Next
 'set up a header for the data dump, this is for CSV
 strEmailContents = "Email" & vbCrLf

 'likely should have some error handling here, in case we have found no target folder
 'Set myFolderItem = outlookFolder.Items
 ' I have commenteted out some items to illustrate the call to Sue'strEmailContents Function
 If Not outlookFolder Is Nothing Then
     For Each outlookMessage In outlookFolder.Items
        If TypeOf outlookMessage Is MailItem Then
          strMsgBody = outlookMessage.Body  ' assign message body to a Var
          ' then use Sue Moshers code to look for stuff in the body
          ' all of the following stuff in the quotes "" is specific to your needs

          strEmailContents = strEmailContents & ParseTextLinePair(strMsgBody, "E-mail:               ")
          strEmailContents = strEmailContents & "," & ParseTextLinePair(strMsgBody, "")
          'add the email message time stamp, just cause i want it

          'debug message comment it out for production
           'WScript.echo strEmailContents
           End If
     Next
 End If
```

Here is my function to parse the lines:

```
Function ParseTextLinePair(strSource, strLabel)
    ' Sue Moshers code
    'commented out type declaration for VBS usgage take out fer VB usage
    Dim intLocLabel 'As Integer
    Dim intLocCRLF 'As Integer
    Dim intLenLabel 'As Integer
    Dim strText 'As String

    ' locate the label in the source text
    intLocLabel = InStr(strSource, strLabel)
    intLenLabel = Len(strLabel)
        If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, strSource, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            strText = Mid(strSource, _
                            intLocLabel, _
                            intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
            intLocLabel = Mid(strSource, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If
    ParseTextLinePair = Trim(strText)   ' this i like
End Function
```

Here is an example of an email I am trying to parse; i have put it in code format so it is easier to read.

```
Vendor: 22*********** 


  Your company may be interested in the following advertisement(s).  
  To learn more about the advertisements below, please visit the  
  ******** Vendor Bid System (VBS) at  
  http://www.****************.com. For specific  
  questions about the solicitation, each advertisement includes  
  contact information for the agency representative who issued it.  
  to view additional information on the advertisement(s) listed  
  below.  

  ____________________________________________________________  
  Agency:     ***************************************  
  Agency Ads: http://www.*************.com  

  Advertisement Number: ******BLACKEDOUT INFO***********  
  Advertisement Type:   Informational Notice  
  Title:                Centralized Customer Service System (CCSS) - Notice of Public Meeting  
  Advertisement Status: New  
  Agency Contact:       Sheree ***** 
  E-mail:               blah@aol.com  
  Telephone:            (000)-000-0000
```

Thank you in advanced!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Alright sir, give this a shot. Make sure you designate your folder and searchtext at the top. A message box will popup once the email has been extracted.

```
Sub ParseContents()

    Dim strTargetFolder : strTargetFolder = "Inbox"
    Dim SearchText: SearchText = "Email: "    

    Dim NS As outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oFld As outlook.Folder
    Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    For ifld = 1 To NS.Folders.Count
        For ictr = 1 To NS.Folders.Item(ifld).Folders.Count
            ' handle case sensitivity as I can't type worth a crap
            If LCase(NS.Folders.Item(ifld).Folders(ictr).Name) = LCase(strTargetFolder) Then
                'found our target :)
                Set oFld = NS.Folders.Item(ifld).Folders(ictr)
                Exit For  ' found it so lets move on
            End If
        Next
    Next
    'set up a header for the data dump, this is for CSV
    strEmailContents = "Email" & vbCrLf

    Dim EscapeLoops: EscapeLoops = False
    'likely should have some error handling here, in case we have found no target folder
    'Set myFolderItem = outlookFolder.Items
    ' I have commenteted out some items to illustrate the call to Sue'strEmailContents Function
    If Not oFld Is Nothing Then
        For Each outlookMessage In oFld.Items
            If TypeOf outlookMessage Is MailItem Then
                If InStr(outlookMessage.Body, SearchText) Then
                    strMsgBody = outlookMessage.Body  ' assign message body to a Var
                    ' then use Sue Moshers code to look for stuff in the body
                    ' all of the following stuff in the quotes "" is specific to your needs
                    Dim splitter, parsemail: splitter = Split(strMsgBody, vbCrLf)
                    For Each splt In splitter
                        If InStr(splt, SearchText) Then
                            parsemail = splt
                            EscapeLoops = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    strEmailContents = strEmailContents & "Date/Time: " & outlookMessage.CreationTime & vbCrLf
                    strEmailContents = strEmailContents & ParseTextLinePair(parsemail, SearchText)
                    MsgBox strEmailContents
                    If EscapeLoops Then Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
Function ParseTextLinePair(strSource, strLabel)
    Dim Rturn
    If InStr(strSource, vbCrLf) Then
        Rturn = Mid(strSource, InStr(strSource, strLabel) + Len(strLabel), InStr(strSource, vbCrLf) - InStr(strSource, strLabel) + Len(strLabel)):
    Else
        Rturn = Mid(strSource, InStr(strSource, strLabel) + Len(strLabel))
    End If
ParseTextLinePair = Trim(Rturn)
End Function
```

Comment: That didn't solve my problem, so I'm guessing it must have something to do with my top chunk of code

Comment: That's because you never clearly stated your problem. You said it was parsing incorrectly. I need more information, an example of what your parsing and what you want to get back from the parsing. Otherwise it's just, "Yuuuup, dems some split texts right ther"

Comment: I'm trying to parse a line out of the body of an email...So in the body at one point, it says "Email: blah@aol.com" and I'm trying to parse the email address that comes after "Email:" and the code for that is in the first code block. It isn't parsing correctly because when I open the excel file, only "Email" is there and that's because Im manually printing that out

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. So, in your original code you have it parse on `"Email:(many spaces)"`. Instead of adding spaces after the `Email:` segment. Just leave out the spaces, if there are to many spaces or to few, the `Instr()` statement will mess it up. Plus, you `trim` the result anyway at the end. Remove the spaces and try it again.

Comment: Yeah I had it like that originally and it didn't work, and in the email body, for some reason there is several spaces between "Email:" and "blah@aol.com" so that's why I included the spaces in between; but I got rid of the spaces and tried again and still no luck.

Comment: Would you mind copying and pasting the body of an email you are trying to parse and placing it in your question? it would help immensely

Comment: I have copy and pasted the email body

Comment: Ok. Give that one a shot.

Comment: Give what one a shot?

Comment: That kind of works... It parses a random email and will spit out the e-mail address line i need, but i need it to go through the entire folder and extract the e-mail address from every email in the folder, idk why it's choosing one at random

Comment: Then remove the `If EscapeLoops Then Exit For` and it'll go through all emails in that folder and spit out the email address, also, if this parsed the email correctly as your question asked, please mark this as an answer.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you and i have marked it as an answer